# I need a translation from Moroccan to English

Tags: spices

My mother brought some spices back from her holiday in Morocco but I can't seem to find a translation of them they are

- Cuorre
- Pikante
- Pimante Negra
- Pimante Rojo
- Kanela
- Comeno
- 7 Especais Mexta
- Jengebre
- Courcuoma

Comment: Welcome! I've added bullets to your list. The way our formatting works, you need to either use double returns, bullets, or add a double space at the end of a line to have it actually break when it's rendered.

Comment: A lot of that looks like french.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek not at all. Reads like a mix of Spanish, Italian and a pinch of Portuguese with some "creativity" thrown in.

Answer (score 3):

After a quick googling and just looking at the words.

- Cuorre Pikante : Crushed Red Pepper Flakes
- Pimante Negra : Black peppercorn.
- Pimante Rojo : Pink peppercorn.
- Kanela : Cinnamon
- Comeno : Maybe the brand name of the 7 spice mix ?
- 7 Especais Mexta : 7 Spice mix.
- Jengebre : Ginger
- Courcuoma : Curcuma/Turmeric

Comment: Comeno - if I had to guess... "cumin". As a note, if you looked at the markup for the post, all of the items were on separate lines. I've added bullets now, to make it more clear, though.

Comment: Curcuma is more commonly called turmeric in English, I think.